# What i need to use in new flutter update on stream builder .?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

```
import 'package:bank_job_bangladesh/Screens/userpostpannel/models/constants.dart';
import 'package:bank_job_bangladesh/Screens/userpostpannel/pages/userpostpannelhomepage.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ChatPagePGovtBank extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChatPagePGovtBankState createState() => _ChatPagePGovtBankState();
}

class _ChatPagePGovtBankState extends State<ChatPagePGovtBank> {
  final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  late String massageText;

  // void getMassages() async {
  //   final massages =
  //       await _firestore.collection('govtchatgroup massages').get();
  //   for (var massage in massages.docs) {
  //     print(massage.data());
  //   }
  // }

  void getMassageStream() async {
    await for (var snapshot
        in _firestore.collection('govtchatgroup massages').snapshots()) {
      for (var massage in snapshot.docs) {
        print(massage.data()['text']);
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: null,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.close),
              onPressed: () {
                getMassageStream();
                //getMassages();
                //Implement logout functionality
              }),
        ],
        title: Text('⚡️Chat'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              decoration: kMessageContainerDecoration,
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        massageText = value;
                        //Do something with the user input.
                      },
                      decoration: kMessageTextFieldDecoration,
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      _firestore.collection('govtchatgroup massages').add({
                        'text': massageText,
                        'sender': currentUser!.email,
                        'display name': currentUser!.displayName,
                      });
                      //Implement send functionality.
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Send',
                      style: kSendButtonTextStyle,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: _firestore
                  .collection('govtchatgroup massage')
                  .orderBy('orderId', descending: true)
                  .snapshots(),
              //_firestore.collection('govtchatgroup massage').snapshots(),
              builder: ( context , snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  final messages = snapshot.data!.docs;
                  List<Text> messageWidgets = [];
                  for (var message in messages) {
                    final  messgetText = message.data()!['text'] ;
                     final messageSender = message.data()!['sender'];
                  
                  }
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

On here i am getting error on                                          **final  messgetText = message.data()!['text'] ;
final messageSender = message.data()!['sender']**                                Error massage shows:                                                        The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try defining the operator '[]'.dart(undefined_operator)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2HQV.png)

Comment: The result of message.data() is Object, but not a Map, so Dart can't use it as a Map. You have to use something like this - (message.data() as Map)['sender'].

Comment: Really it worked, Thank you. But why i need to do that now, i mean this update changed the code?

Comment: If I understood you properly, now you have to return some widget(ListView for example) from your  builder: ( context , snapshot) method, to display loaded data.